# msvcp100.dll is missing - a more informative error

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have a lot of users reporting that they get the "msvcp100.dll is missing" error.

Instead of having users keep reporting this and reply that they need to install the C++ redistributable I would like to change the error text into something more meaningful, e.g. tell them that they need to install C++ redist.

Is this possible?

Comment: A better solution might be to include the redistributable's merge module in your installation package. Is something preventing you from doing so?

Comment: I don't have and don't want an installation package, it should run out of the box, so to say.

Comment: Just ran across this...and I would argue that it's a requirement for applications to include all required files rather than forcing the user to hunt down redistributable files.

Look at this from a cost perspective.  Your support team is wasting a lot of time having to repeatedly explain why the user has to install a redistributable package...when spending a little time to create an MSI-based installer would alleviate all of it...not to mention provide a better user experience to your customers...along with the option to uninstall the program should they need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to force users to install the redistributable, you can statically link to the runtime. Go to your `Project Settings` and find `C/C++` >> `Code Generation`. Change the `runtime library` setting to `multithreaded` (`/MT`) instead of `multithreaded dll` (`/MTd`).

Comment: Although I guess this also requires that all third-party libraries are compiled with /MT.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is possible to change the error message. I highly doubt this because it is an error of the loader of the OS.
So why don't you create an installer for your application that will do the checking and if necessary the installation of the redist package?

Comment: +1 Possible solution, but it feels a little silly to create an installer just for the redist.

Answer (score 0):

You can also include in your application's release version the dll's that your application are needed